# Shifting leftView of UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitextfield

I try to customize my `UITextField` object as it[image]

but `leftView` is shifting right by some pixels as it

[image]

how can i change position of my `UITextField.leftView`

Here is my code

```
NSArray *itemArray = @[@"<", @">"];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 26);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;


_urlTextField.leftView = segmentedControl;
_urlTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: Can you try segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(-10, 0, 60, 26);.It is not right but just try.

Comment: yes, i try this, but have no effect

Comment: Try changing the segmentControl style to something else..

Comment: Did you try this method - (CGRect)leftViewRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
NSArray *itemArray = @[@"<", @">"];
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
  **segmentedControl.center = CGPointMake(03, 15);**
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;


self.textField.leftView = segmentedControl;
self.textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Also change your textfield's border style to other than round rect..

Hope this helps

Regards,
Paggy123

Comment: Yes you are right in "Also change your textfield's border style".
`segmentedControl.center = CGPointMake(03, 15);` have no effect...

Answer (score 1):

UITextField doesn't provide a property like `frame` for `leftView`; it having only one property like bounds makes it like navigation controller bar button items positions; we cant change the `leftView` position . [See here for reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)